# How to grant apt-get permissions required to install software?

Tags: installation, command-line

I am new to Linux, can anyone be kind enough to help me know how to install software from the terminal?

I tried to install java by entering the command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

but i get errors ,

```
E:Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E:Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I also tried root

```
su -
```

but it says that the password is incorrect, so what is root ?

Advance Thanks for the help Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `sudo`, you are temporarily becoming root for the duration of that command, just like you'd switched to root with `su - root`, executed the command, and switched back with `exit`.

Out of the box, Ubuntu doesn't configure a password for root, so you cannot log in as root directly like you're attempting to do with `su`. You either have to use `sudo`, or configure a password for the root user. It is recommended that you simply use `sudo`.

Are you sure you used `sudo` when trying to run the install command?

Comment: To summarize, are you sure you used `sudo` when you ran the first command?

If so, then maybe another package manager is running at the same time, though this seems unlikely.

Answer (score -1):

You will get that error if you have the gui (graphic user interface) open. 
Check the desktop, is synaptic package manager open?